# gwt ext helloworld application

Tags: gwt-ext

I am trying to make my HelloWorld Application in GWt Ext from [this](http://gwt-ext.com/wiki/index.php?title=Tutorial%3aIntroduction_to_GWT-Ext_2.0) tutorial

In out HTML class we have to put this line

```
              <script type="text/javascript" src='com.mycompany.mypackage.HelloWorld.nocache.js'></script>
```

can anyone please tell me whats this line is and which path i have to mention here

right now my application is running and GWT shell is opening but there's nothing in it, I see just an empty browser

Answer (score 0):

you should copy the adress(Development Mode in Eclipse, something like:`http://127.0.0.1:8888/******.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`) in the brower, have a try.